# Strange Python numpy array indexing behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array

```
[0. 100. 200. 300. 400. -500. -400. -300. -200. -100.]
```

which I'm trying to rearrange to be from smallest to largest.

I find the turning point from pos to neg which is stored in j.

If I print the following I get

```
>>print(frequencies[4])
400.0
```

BUT

```
>>print(frequencies[0:4-1])
[0. 100. 200. 300.]
```

Why doesn't it go all the way up to 400? Seems like an odd choice of syntax convention.

Comment: If you don't like Python convention, I suggest you build your own language to your own taste...

Comment: how do you get j in your code? what value does it have

Comment: I think it's a good choice. If you have `a = [9, 8, 7, 6]` then `a[0:2] + a[2:4]` will give you `[9, 8, 7, 6]` again. With the `2` you have the same value for the end of the first part and the start of the second part.

Comment: Julien, I think I might just have too.

Comment: See Guido Van Rossum's response: [Why Python uses 0-based indexing](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html)

Comment: 0 indexing makes sense, it's the very counter intuitive to have one the first argument be inclusive and the second be exclusive which is the problem. If you accessing array[0] you get element [0]. If you're accessing [4] you get [4] so why is [0:4] 0, 4 and everything in between. You can make them exclusive if you want but it then choosing only one to be exclusive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost everywhere through Python the behavior is `[)`, meaning the left (or start) argument is inclusive and the right (or end) argument is exclusive. Be it list slicing, string slicing, the `range` function,
 etc.

It only makes sense for `numpy` to follow this convention.

Comment: Except, interestingly, in the [random module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint). It's always bothered me, I'm not sure why they decided to break from convention there.

Comment: @James The random module does not seem to follow even its own convention (or any convention for the matter), see https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random (compare `random.random` to `random.randint` behavior)

Comment: Huh. So I guess it's just `randint`. Weird.